# iPhone emulator, any working out there?

Tags: iphone

I need to play around with a free iPhopne app that I downloaded via iTunes, but I don't have an iPhone. Maybe anybody knows of a good iPhone emulator for Windows that can run *.ipa apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't run Appstore app in the simulator.
There is no way of doing it.

Since the Simulator use the i386 architecture and Appstore apps the arm architecture.